# Apache Server: direct to specific worker based on deployed applications in Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, redirect, proxy, load-balancing

I have a Apache HTTP(s) Server load-balancing between 2 Tomcat servers. I have 4 versions of my application (versions: 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3).

I want to deploy 1.0 and 1.2 on first Tomcat Server and 1.1 and 1.3 on second Tomcat Server. I have created my configuration but it's wrong. When I hit URL www.example.com/app1.0 sometimes the first worker is chosen, sometimes the second worker is chosen because default "byrequests" algorithm is forced by Apache (first Apache choses the worker, then URL is analyzed) and I get 404 error, because the app I want to open isn't deployed on this Tomcat Server. I want make Apache always chose the worker where the app - required in the endpoint - is deployed.

Could someone write a snippet of correct configuration, please?

Answer (score 0):

I backed out from reverse-proxying and load-balancing and implemented RewriteMap. I created a properties file and assigned specific versions of my app to specific workers.